# Daft numbering in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I'd like to construct a special kind of numbering.

In the first cell I'm going to manually write 'AB'.

In the second cell,  immediately below, I'm going to manually write '01'.

So it'll look this...

```
AB
01
```

I want every subsequent cell to be as follows:

```
AB01.001
AB01.002
AB01.003
AB01.004
```

So far, so simple. Here's the catch. I want to be able to rearrage rows 001 to 004, and, when I do,I want them to automatically update with their correct value.

Let me illustrate...

```
ID        Description
AB        
01        
AB01.001  First
AB01.002  Second
AB01.003  Third
AB01.004  Fourth
```

So, let's sat I cut the 'Fourth' row and reinsert it above the 'Second' row. Afterwards, I'd want it to look like this...

```
ID        Description
AB        
01        
AB01.001  First
AB01.002  Fourth
AB01.003  Second
AB01.004  Third
```

If I had been smart, I would have used numbers instead of letters, and a formula such as

```
=SUM(OFFSET([current cell],-1,0)+0.001).
```

But I wasn't smart, and now I'm in this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill cells below `01` with this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("R["&(-1-ROW($A1))&"]C",0)&INDIRECT("R["&(-ROW($A1))&"]C",0)&"."&TEXT(ROW($A1),"000")
```

[image]

**Edit**

For `$C$4=AB`, `$C$5=01`,
this should pass the `cut/insert` catch:

```
=$C$4&$C$5&"."&TEXT(ROW()-ROW($C$5),"000")
```

(tested):

[image]

Comment: Also brilliant - but this also fails the "Here's the catch" test!

Comment: @Strawberry: check out if the edited function works as you expected

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=$A$1&TEXT((SUBSTITUTE(A2,$A$1,"")+0.0001),"00.0000")
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Well done :-) - Ah - except that it doesn't satisfy the "Here's the catch" part!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:
=$A$2&$A$3&"."&TEXT(ROW()-3,"000")
Where:
A2 is AB
A3 is 01
Row() is the number of the row where you place the formula
3 is the number of rows before the row where you place the formula
For example you start the formula in A4, Row() will be 4 and to make it 1 (4-3 or Row()-3) to make the formula start with 001
and you can drag it down

Comment: Also, very cool. I accepted the other answer just because it came in a fraction sooner. Thanks.